# Multiple column sort

Tags: sorting, unique

I have some data in the following format:

```
1298501934.311 42.048
1298501934.311 60.096
1298501934.311 64.128
1298501934.311 64.839
1298501944.203 28.352
1298501966.283 6.144
1298501972.900 0
1298501972.939 0
1298501972.943 0
1298501972.960 0
1298501972.961 0
1298501972.964 0
1298501973.964 28.636
1298501974.215 27.52
1298501974.407 25.984
1298501974.527 27.072
1298501974.527 31.168
1298501974.591 30.144
1298501974.591 31.296
1298501974.83 27.605
1298501975.804 28.096
1298501976.271 23.879
1298501978.488 25.472
1298501978.744 25.088
1298501978.808 25.088
1298501978.936 26.24
1298501979.123 26.048
1298501980.470 23.75
1298501980.86 17.53
1298501982.392 22.336
1298501990.199 8.064
1298501997.943 0.256
1298501997.943 0.448
1298501997.943 0.512
1298501997.943 5.952
1298501997.946 0.448
1298501997.946 0.576
1298501997.946 5.44
```

My goal is to get the maximum value from the right column for each unique value in the left column. For instance, after processing the following 4 lines:

```
1298501997.943 0.256
1298501997.943 0.448
1298501997.943 0.512
1298501997.943 5.952
```

I would like to get just the last line,

```
1298501997.943 5.952
```

since "5.952" is the largest value for `1298501997.943`

Similarly, for the following lines:

```
1298501997.946 0.448
1298501997.946 0.576
1298501997.946 5.44
```

I would like to get:

```
1298501997.946 5.44
```

And for:

```
1298501990.199 8.064
```

simply:

```
1298501990.199 8.064
```

and so on...

I tried searching for some hints in awk/uniq/etc., but not sure even how to formulate the query.
I could write a Python script, but it feels that proceeding with awk or some other standard tools would be more efficient (especially since I have a lot of data - millions/tens of millions of lines).

PS: Is there any Python module for text processing scenarios like that?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you have this data? Just in a text file? In a database? and What would you like to use to sort it? A particular programming language, or do you just want the data (wherever it is) to be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk:

```
{
    if (array[$1] < $2)
        array[$1]=$2
}
END {
    printf("%-20s%s\n", "Value", "Max")
    printf("%-20s%s\n", "-----", "---")
    for (i in array)
        printf("%-20s%s\n", i, array[i])
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f sort.awk log 
Value               Max
-----               ---
1298501980.86       17.53
1298501978.808      25.088
1298501974.215      27.52
1298501973.964      28.636
1298501979.123      26.048
1298501978.936      26.24
1298501975.804      28.096
1298501972.964      
1298501944.203      28.352
1298501974.83       27.605
1298501974.407      25.984
1298501997.943      5.952    <---- as in your example
1298501978.488      25.472
1298501972.939      
1298501972.900      
1298501982.392      22.336
1298501974.527      31.168
1298501997.946      5.44     <---- as in your example
1298501980.470      23.75
1298501974.591      31.296
1298501990.199      8.064    <---- as in your example
1298501966.283      6.144
1298501934.311      64.839
1298501976.271      23.879
1298501972.960      
1298501978.744      25.088
1298501972.961      
1298501972.943
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put it in Excel (importing it by splitting on the SPACE character) and sort it that way. This is a rather brute-force solution, but it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sort -g` does the trick. It is general numeric sort and can handle space.

Comment: That will not do what OP wants: finding maximum of left column for each unique value in the right column.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt python would be significantly less efficient here than other tools (unless you need to process millions of data every fraction of second). You can do something like this:

```
import sys
d={}
for l in open(sys.argv[1]):
    a,b=[float(item) for item in l.split()]
    d[a]=max(d.get(a,b),b)
 for a in d: print a,d[a]
```

and run it with

```
$ python script.py dataFile
```

Answer (score 0):

As a shell one-liner (uses the `-f` argument of `uniq`, which ignores *first* n columns; to ignore the second, columns are swapped twice)

```
cat yourData | sort -g | awk '{print $2,$1};'  | uniq -f1 | awk '{print $2,$1};'
```